# SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK compare against TextFrame.contents

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting

```
var myStories = app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().getElements();
for (i = myStories.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var myTextFrames = myStories[i].textContainers;
    $.writeln(myTextFrames.length);
    for (j = myTextFrames.length - 1; j >= 0; j--)    {
        $.writeln(myTextFrames[j].contents);
        if (myTextFrames[j].contents == SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK){
            $.writeln("test hier");
            myTextFrames[j].remove();
        }
    }
}
```

why does this not work? I guess because the `SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK` is a number but I cannot make it work, I tried so much.

The condition gets never true even if there only a pagebreak in the textframe.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the `contents` property seems to only return string objects. I am not sure why exactly that is the case, but the `SpecialCharacters` can be used for writing only in a script context (somebody correct me, if I am wrong, please). So the most simple way to check for a single page break in a text frame would be to simply check for a break in that frame:

```
if(myTextFrames[j].contents === "\r")
```

Note that this will also return true for column breaks, frame breaks etc. If you need to find page breaks only, I think you need to script a GREP search for page breaks, which would be a bit more involved.

Btw. it would be nice, if you could ask your question with an actual explanation of your problem and what the code is supposed to do, instead of only pasting some code and asking, why it does not work. People are much more likely to help you, if you help them understand your problem quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you are looking for but mdomino is right. You did not ask any question. To check if your textframe or story has a `SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK` character you cant compare the whole `contents` of a `textFrame`. You need to examine each character on its own. This code should get do what you want.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var story = doc.stories[0];
for(var i = 0; i < story.characters.length; i++) {
  if(story.characters.item(i).contents === SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK) {
    $.writeln('found the page break SpecialCharacters.PAGE_BREAK at index ' + i);
  }
}
```